# How to assign an auto number value to relation ship id? is it possible

Tags: apex, soql

How to assign an auto number value to relation ship id? is it possible

I have Custom Objects for example Parent_*c which has a field **'NAME'**(which is similar to Id) which is  autonumber datatype. I have an another set of child custom objects (Child*_c) which has a field **'ID'** which gives the Master-Detail relation ship

Below here i have used aggregate query to fetch max of the id,

```
  List<AggregateResult> maxId = [SELECT Max(Name)Id FROM Parent__c ];
  Object maximumId = null;

  if(maxId!=null && !maxId.isEmpty()){

        maximumId =    maxId.get(0).get('Id');
        System.debug('Maximum Id ::'+maximumId );                    
  }

  Child__c c = new Child__c();
  c.Id = maximumId; **// But here i will not be able to assign object value to Id filed.**
```

What is the way i need to proceed? Is it right way i'm doing it?

Then how can i link the records with Parent to Child.

Kindly somebody help me and let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grabbing the `Name` of the `Parent__c` that has the maximal value.  Since this is an aggregation, this `Name` *may* belong to multiple records.  But since you are auto-numbering the name field, there is a 1-1 correspondence between `Name` and `Id`.  I see two routes on getting the `Id` of the record with maximal `Name` value:

(1)  Grab the maximal Name value via an AggregeResult query (like you've done above), and then perform one more query to grab the unique record corresponding to the Name you aggregated (because you really need the `Id` of the record with maximal `Name` value, not the `Name` itself).

Example:

```
List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT Max(Name)maxName FROM Parent__c];
string maxName = '';

if(arList!=null && !arList.isEmpty())
    maxName = (string)arList[0].get(maxName);   // <--- make sure to cast the data type!

list<Parent__c> parentList = [SELECT id,Name /* important fields */
                              FROM Parent__c
                              WHERE Name=:maxName
                              LIMIT 1];
Parent__c myParent = new Parent__c();
if(parentList!=null && !parentList.isEmpty())
    myParent = parentList[0];
```

---

Or (2):  Find the parent record via one query.  (This can only be done because there is a 1-1 map between `Parent__c.Name` and `Parent__c.id`!  Make sure you understand why.)

Example:

```
list<Parent__c> parentList = [SELECT id,Name /* import fields */
                              FROM Parent__c
                              ORDER BY Name DESC // <-- grabs the Name with maximal value
                              LIMIT 1];  
Parent__c myParent = new Parent__c();
if(parentList!=null && !parentList.isEmpty())
    myParent = parentList[0];
```

---

Using either method, you end up with the desired `Parent__c` record.  Next, just attach the Id to the `Child__c` record.

```
Child__c c = new Child__c();
c.Id = myParent.id;
```

Comment: Not entirely correct. There may be a many-to-one relationship between the `Name` and `Id` value; since administrators are free to change the starting point of the auto-number field at any time, this can cause overlap. It is never, ever safe to assume that Name is somehow globally unique.

Comment: @sfdcfox With above given 2nd  option, currently suits my requirement. As per your valid comments *'since administrators are free to change the starting point of the auto-number field at any time'* what is the best way to mitigate this issue?. Kindly guide us how to proceed?

Comment: my method surely uses the fact that "This can only be done because there is a 1-1 map between Parent__c.Name and Parent__c.id! Make sure you understand why."

If you have a many-1 relationship, you need a way to tease out the record you actually want.  This is completely determined on how everything is set up.

Comment: If you are always looking for the oldest record, you can compare records by **CreatedDate**